# What is the name this part of Visual Studio Code and how can I hide it?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have this bar (marked below) on the right side of my `editor area`. I can't see any setting in `view` tab that could hide it. Is there setting that can hide it?

[image]

Comment: That is the `minimap` - there is a setting to hide it.

Comment: Thank you. That works.